# Html in-page hidden text that isn't shown until link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

sort of new to html. I'm looking to create animation that when am image is clicked, it plays an animation that splits open a half page of text and in stuff. Something like this: http://sketchtoy.com/62368639

Comment: The page that you have pointed,uses HTML5 Canvas element,you can read about it at here:http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Comment: Do you mean something like google's image search, where you click on an image and it opens up the box where you get the image and "view site" "view image" buttons, or how it used to be i think they have since changed their layout

Comment: @Hbirjand, OP is not asking how to make that page, OP wants what the sketch is showing

Comment: @Patrick, exactly like google's image search.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do things like that, you should really have a look at a javascript framework like jquery (www.jquery.com)

I find this one particularly easy to learn.

For what you want to do:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="mytext">Your text</div>
<a onclick="$('#mytext').show()"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic process is

1. Add the click handler for the images
2. Find the last image in the row that the clicked image is in
3. set the contents of the expanding element
4. insert the expanding element after the image from step 2
5. show the expanding element (in this case a slideDown animation)

This is using jQuery library, which you did not tag, but it makes doing this a lot easier. If you need a vanilla javascript approach one can be added.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/128x64" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/128x64" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/128x64" />

    <div id="expander">
        <img src="" />
        <div id="info">
            some info
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
//Just making the expander half the height of the viewport
var winheight = $(window).height();
$("#expander").css("height",winheight/2);

$("img").click(function(){
   var img = $(this);
   var src = img.attr("src");
   var afterImg = findLastImgInRow(img);
   var expander = $("#expander");

   //Hide the expander if previously open
   expander.hide(0);

   //just setting the insides
   expander.find("img").attr("src",src);
   expander.find("#info").html("This is a test");

   //Put the expander after the last image in the row
   //so it will appear between its row and the next 
   expander.insertAfter(afterImg);
   expander.slideDown(600);    

   //This scrolls the page so that it will make the 
   //expander appear in the middle of the page
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: expander.offset().top-(winheight/4)
   }, 600);   
});

//Function to find the last image
//in a row by comparing their offset top values
function findLastImgInRow(img){
   var imgTop = img.offset().top;
   var img2 = img;
   do{
       if( img2.offset().top != imgTop ){
           img2 = img2.prev();
           break;
       }
   }while(img2=img2.next());
   return img2;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cdnk/)